# Loading ruby packages outside rails Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I've recently downloaded a ruby extension (Nokogiri) using the `gem install` command and I would like to use it outside rails, in a small script I'm writing. When I use it in rails, it works perfectly, but how to load it outside rails? Which files should I need to 'require'? (I don't seem to find the downloaded source)

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this guide](http://ruby.about.com/od/gems/a/nokogiri.htm) for using nokogiri.

Basically you just do

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
```

and you're set up.

There's also some useful general information on using gems in ruby code [here](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/4#page16).

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well! I'm going to take a look on the reference you gave me.